# How could I pass variable referrence out of batch using trigger so that i wouldn't need to hardcode

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, database-trigger

Seems like I couldn't get across my issue properly so I've decided to re-ask my question in a different shape. I  have two tables named **SALES_TABLE** and **PRODUCT_TABLE**. So whenever I sell an item from the product table, the number of the sold item(@sale_count) is subtracted from the total number of the same item in the stock (pr_stock) and the result gets displayed on the Product_table while the figures for product id, sale number, and the product name is supposed to be triggered with :

```
INSERT INTO DBO.SALES_TABLE (SALE_COUNT,PROD_ID,Prod_name) VALUES (3,4, @prd_name )
```

and inserted into Sales_table. However, @prd_name reference which was initialized with Product_name from Product Table where PRODUCT_id = @PRD_ID gives the error since it's out of Begin and END block.

"You must declare scalar variable @prd_name".

So how to make @prd_name variable to be passed out of the batch so that I could avoid hardcoding Product_name into the sale_table?

```
alter TRIGGER DBO.TRG_STOCK
    ON DBO.SALES_TABLE
    AFTER INSERT
    AS
    BEGIN

    DECLARE @SALE_COUNT INT
    DECLARE @PRD_ID INT 
    declare @prd_name varchar(20) 

    SELECT @PRD_ID = PROD_ID, @SALE_COUNT = SALE_COUNT FROM INSERTED
    select @prd_NAME = PRODUCT_NAME from PRODUCT_TABLE where PRODUCT_id = @PRD_ID
    UPDATE PRODUCT_TABLE SET PR_STOCK =  PR_STOCK - @SALE_COUNT WHERE PRODUCT_id = @PRD_ID
    END


    INSERT INTO DBO.SALES_TABLE (SALE_COUNT,PROD_ID,Prod_name) VALUES (3,4, @prd_name )
```

Note that:

```
INSERT INTO DBO.SALES_TABLE (SALE_COUNT,PROD_ID,Prod_name) VALUES (3,4, @prd_name )
```

is not the part of the trigger, it's what should trigger the script in the Begin and the End clause

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the case where multiple rows are inserted in a single statement, as SQL Server has *statement triggers*, not *row triggers*.  So something like this:

```
alter TRIGGER DBO.TRG_STOCK
ON DBO.SALES_TABLE
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    with sold as
    (
      select prod_id, sum(sale_count) sale_count
      from inserted
      group by prod_id
    ), prod as
    (
      select p.prod_id, p.pr_stock, sold.sale_count
      from sold
      join product_table p
        on sold.prod_id = p.prod_id
    )
    update prod set pr_stock = pr_stock - sale_count;

END
```

Additionally you appear to be inserting the product_name in the sales table instead of the product_id, which you shouldn't be doing.  But you can make that work by changing the joins.